# JQuery Mobile Popup with Canvas

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am looking to create a popup in Jquery Mobile which has a canvas embedded in it.

The trick is that I need the popup/cavans to launch in landscape mode.. no matter the current orientation of the screen?

Any advice?

Thanks

Comment: so if the user is holding the device in portrait mode, you want the whole popup rotated 90 degrees, or just the contents of the canvas?

Comment: Yes.  That is it exactly.  I am making a signature app (using html Canvas).. and I want the canvas to show up in a popup, full screen, portrait mode.  I have the canvas/jquery working for the signature... I'm just trying to figure out the popup/landscape issue.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a CSS transform on the popup content to rotate it 90 degrees when you detect the device is in portrait mode.

Create a CSS class that performs the rotation (-90 for counter clockwise, 90 for clockwise):

```
.rotateCCW {
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

Then on the popup `popupbeforeposition` event, check the orientation and either add or remove the CSS class:

```
$("#popupDialog").on("popupbeforeposition", function(event, ui) {
    if (is_landscape()){
        $("#popupDialog").removeClass("rotateCCW");
    } else {
        $("#popupDialog").addClass("rotateCCW");            
    }    
});

function is_landscape() {
  return (window.orientation === 90 || window.orientation === -90);
}
```

> Here is a **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/d695oq4w/4/)**